# Move fileshare from one folder to another with Wix

Tags: wix, fileshare

I have a fileshare named Inbox on server, pointing on Folder1. My installer needs to delete this fileshare and create it on the Folder2. Wix doesn't do that by default and even processes with no error, creating nothing but Folder2 itself (not shared). Is it possible?

Comment: Are you using FileShare element: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_fileshare.htm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WiX does not support deleting shares except on uninstall.